# Cross Server (WFE) Communication (for example for memorycache invalidation)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cache

As far as i know you cannot use appfabric for your own custom object caching in sharepoint 2013 right? I have the necessity to invalidate the cache on certain events across the whole farm.

I found this article on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177889/how-do-i-update-an-expensive-in-memory-cache-across-a-sharepoint-farm

Sadly "service applications" are very very poorly documented and I'm not sure if it would actually help. I would still need the service application to "inform" the specific web applications about the cache invalidation. I cannot think of another way than providing a simple http handler or aspx page to take care of that. Or has a service application some mysterious way to interact with a web application?

Example:
Service Application "cache notification dispatcher"
-> http://app01.local/_layouts/15/cache.ashx?action=invaldiate&key=myKey
(of course this has to be done per frontend (machine name) which is fairly easy)

In theory it should work - and frontends could register at the service application (so it knows where to dispatch any cache actions) to automate things even further. However it feels like a huge workaround for not being able to use any of the built-in AppFabric functionality.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing too constructive, but correct, you would put yourself in an unsupported state if you used SharePoint's AppFabric cache for your own objects. You can set up your own AppFabric cache instance, of course.